# Regarding reload issue in next js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I am facing an issue in the next js production build is whenever I uploaded it on the hosting and refresh any page it gives an error 404 and whenever I go directly to specific pages its again gives error 404 but when I go from the home page its work fine.

Please help me out

Comment: did you tried it running locally first? like next build then next start?

Comment: Yes at locally it is working fine

Comment: Where are you hosting it? My guess is it'll work if you put `.html` at the end of the path. Let me know.

Comment: I have hosted on aws and i am generation the pages they are in the .HTML extension but it is still not working

Comment: Please help to share the code and structure so will get a better understanding

Comment: so going to /pagethatthrows404.html does the same as without the HTML extension? The issue I had with Next (with firebase) was I had to set a `cleanUrls` flag to true, to remove the .HTML extension from the pages.

Comment: tried but not able to resolve the issue